# How to get a transparent notification/Quickmenu background?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.4-kitkat

I want my Galaxy SIII Int to have a transparent notification/quickmenu background, without Gravitybox it aint working. The problem, if I use Gravitybox my system.ui will crash.

So I searched other ways to do it and came with ''[MOD][XPOSED]Change notification background image[UPDATE 1.1]'' But also that aint working for me know...

So if some of you guys know a way to do it, please tell me.

Phone info:
- Samsung Galaxy SIII International 
- KitKat 4.4.2
- CyanogenMod 11 ( Snapshot M3 )

Comment: Are you using GravityBox[KK] for KitKat and not GravityBox[JB]? It should work fine, as it is for AOSP like ROMs. Failign that as the answer below says try other modules!

Comment: Yes exactly that, Im using GravityBox KK with my SGS 3 International with CM 11 KitKat. But if i restart it says System.ui has chrashed ?

Answer (score 1):

If GravityBox isn't working for you, I'd try another XPOSED mod called Wanam Xposed. It's similar to GB in the sense that you can modify all kinds of different parts of your phone using it, but Wanam is a lot better when it comes to modifying the status bar, in my opinion.

Comment: I already heard of Wanam Xposed but I dont see the option to transparate your notification menu ?

Comment: Should be under the category 'Theme', and in the  subcategory 'Notification panel'.